# Including Jquery in magento conflict the prototype.js

Tags: magento-1, jquery

I cannot include Jquery in magento because after including jquery-2.2.2.min.js in magento admin side,it have conflict with prototype.js.
Adding `$.noConflict();` can remove the conflict,but the jquery will not work then.This is the actual problem.

Comment: what do the 2 tags magento2 and magento-1.7 mean?

Comment: I mean magento-1.I removed the tags

Comment: check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183012/how-can-i-include-jquery-in-magento

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict()` removes the conflict (not `$.noConflict()` because `$` still belongs to Prototype.js). Please show an example of a script that does not work then. You probably use `$` in the global scope. Instead you should either use `jQuery`, or wrap any jQuery code in a closure like this: `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`

Comment: i think this question and this user could be removed from SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can just include jquery using below way, in template file,

```
<script>
   require(["jquery"],function($){
      ///your jquery code
   });
</script>
```

Comment: But its showing  require is not defined.Cannot use this script

Comment: Run php command from your magneto root, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I didn't get you. Actually when iinclude jquery in my phtml file it have conflict with prototype.js. It can avoid using your method?

Comment: can you show your full code?

Comment: actually include  <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js') ?>hpp/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in magento admin

Comment: file is adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/billing/method/form.phtml.

Comment: are you talking about magento 1 or 2?

Comment: talking about magento1

Comment: sorry,I removed it.Please help me

Comment: your question is a very basilar, it means google is full of tutorial to do it, check it here https://www.google.it/search?q=magento+1+add+jquery&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIT751IT752&oq=magento+1+add+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.4470j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your jquery file in `js` directory
2. Add the following code to your layout .xml file in respective handle. For Ex:  to reflect in all pages

This should fall under `<reference name="head">`

```
  <action method="addJs">
       <script>path/to/your/jquery</script>
  </action>
```